# NPSP - Batch Apex Error Inactive user

Tags: apex, batch, npsp

I received an email from SF with the below three errors.  I have tried looking through other similar questions about Inactive Owner errors and they are all program-speak.  I am no programmer.  How do I find out who the inactive user is?  Once the user is found, can I simply change the user and go on with life?

here are the error messages received.
Errors:

---

Error #1:

> Error Type: Batch Apex error
>   Error Date: 2017-07-25 05:00:20
>   Message: "First error: [INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER] owner or user is inactive. Org Id:00D61000000ccgs User Id:00561000002Gv7z"
>   Context: npsp__ALLO_Rollup_SCHED
>
> Stack Trace:
>    null

---

Error #2:

> Error Type: Batch Apex error
>   Error Date: 2017-07-25 05:00:14
>   Message: "First error: [INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER] owner or user is inactive. Org Id:00D61000000ccgs User Id:00561000002Gv7z"
>   Context: npsp__RLLP_OppContactRollup_BATCH
>
> Stack Trace:
>    null

---

Error #3:

> Error Type: Batch Apex error
>   Error Date: 2017-07-25 05:00:14
>   Message: "First error: [INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER] owner or user is inactive. Org Id:00D61000000ccgs User Id:00561000002Gv7z"
>   Context: npsp__RLLP_OppHouseholdRollup_BATCH
>
> Stack Trace:
>    null

Comment: I'm not familiar with the NPSP namespace, but to give you a bit of help - if you want to identify who those users are, you can copy the 15-character user ID from the error that starts with '005', and search it in global search at the top of Salesforce. Alternatively, you can replace `userid` in the following URL with the 15-character id: `/userid?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1` and append it to your salesforce URL after .com if you're in Setup, and it will take you directly to the user record...